# Simplify overlapping And condition statements

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

I'm trying to figure out the best way to simplify conditional statements that are of the form:

```
if( ( A() && B() ) || ( B() && C() ) || ( C() && D() ) || .... )
{
    code
}
```

The A/B/C/D/etc functions are relatively expensive, so it's not ideal that they could each be called twice.

Two alternatives I've thought of:

```
bool a = A();
bool b = B();
bool c = C();
bool d = D();
if( ( a && b ) || ( b && c ) || ( c && d ) || .... )
{
    code
}
```

This version is not ideal because C(), D(), and any additional conditions are evaluated every time even if A() and B() were both true.  In the original version, they wouldn't have been called at all in that case.

```
bool b = B();
if( ( A() && b ) )
{
    code
}
else
{
    bool c = C();
    if( ( b && c ) )
    {
        code
    }
    else
    {
        bool d = D();
        if( ( c && D ) )
        {
            code
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This version avoids any duplicate and unnecessary conditions from being evaluated, but is incredibly verbose and painful to write.

So I'm hopeful that there's some simpler but equally effective way to write it that I'm not thinking of...?

Comment: is the ... just `a && d` or are there more conditions?

Comment: I mean there might be ( D() && E() ) || ( E() && F() ), etc afterwards.  Not necessarily just 4 functions being checked, there may be more.  But in each case the pattern is the same where each function is being called twice(in the original version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool a = A(), b, c, d;
if (((b = B()) && a) || ((c = C()) && b) || (d = D() && c) || ...) {
    // code;
}
```

Here if `a` is false, `B()` is evaluated for next condition check. In the second condition, if `b` is false, `C()` is evaluated for its next condition. In this way, we can make sure every function is evaluated when needed. But for the last condition, we should use function evaluation as the second operand.

Comment: I personally find this code notably harder to read than the sample in the OP. If I were reading the code in the OP, I'd be concerned of the duplicated calls to `A`, `B`, etc, but in here, I'd struggle to even understand what this code is doing / why it's written in this way. That's not to say that you shouldn't write this, but that if you do write this, please leave a comment explaining why you wrote the code this way, including why the `&&` expressions are in the opposite order I would expect

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to an [`adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find), but using `adjacent_find` would require reevaluating `A`, `B`, etc sometimes. We can write our own version of it that handles this by customizing on a predicate, rather than on "comparing equal":

```
template <typename FwdIter, typename Pred>
FwdIter find_if_consecutive(FwdIter cur, FwdIter last, Pred pred) {
    if (cur == last) return last;

    bool curMatches = false, nextMatches = pred(*cur);

    for (auto next = std::next(cur); next != last; ++cur, ++next) {
        curMatches = std::exchange(nextMatches, pred(*next));
        if (curMatches && nextMatches) return cur;
        // Note: this *might* possibly be faster by moving
        // forward by 2 when `nextMatches` is false, which
        // avoids one of the `curMatches && nextMatches`.
        // Implementation left as an exercise for the reader.
    }

    return last;
}
```

This can then be used like so, if `A`, `B`, `C`, ... can all be function pointers of the same type:

```
auto fns = { A, B, C, D }; // Create an initializer_list

return fns.end()
    != find_if_consecutive(fns.begin(), fns.end(), [](auto f) { return f(); });
```

<sup>[Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lqiwoRDs15rTB8gu)</sup>

---

If we can't put the different expressions into a homogeneous type, we'd need a heterogeneous algorithms library; perhaps Boost Hana would work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use assignment expressions within the `if`.

```
bool b,c;
if (((b = B()) && A()) || ((c = C()) && b) || (c && D()) )    {
    cout << "done";
}
```

As pointed out by @abdullah, one has to take care that due to shortcut evaluation, variable `b` might not have been initialized when used in the condition after the `||`. So the expressions which's result shall be reused later must be on the left hand side of an `&&`-operator, which might introduce unnecessary evaluations.

A way to avoid this would be to use a tristate logic where the variable "knows" if it has been assigned yet. C++ does not have tristate booleans, but it can be simulated easily through data type `int`:

```
int a = A();
int b=-1;
int c=-1;
int d=-1;

if(
   ( a && (b=B()) ) || ( (b<0?b=B():b) && (c=C()) ) || ( (c<0?c=C():c) && (d=D()) )
   )
{
    cout << "done";
}
```

Comment: If `a` is false, then `b` is undefined.

Comment: @abdullah, you are right, but this can be fixed by reversing the order of evaluation. `((b=B()) && a ) || ((c=C()) && b) || ((d=D()) && c) || ...`. I think this imposes no extra function calls.

Comment: I think `B()` must be evaluated even if `A()` is false. Because you need it for 2nd condition. If 1st condition is false, then `C()` must be evaluated even if `b` is false. Because you need it for third condition. This process continues until the last one. At that time you should evaluate the function as the 2nd operand. Please check my answer as well as try with some use cases. I hope my explanation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

One version involves saving all the functions into a `std::vector<std::function<bool()>>`, which creates very simple calling-conventions and simplifies the logic:

```
#include<vector>
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>

bool evaluate_vec(std::vector<std::function<bool()>> const& funcs) {
    bool a, b;
    for (size_t index = 0; index < funcs.size(); index++) {
        //We'll ping-pong between the two cached evaluations of the variables
        if ((index & 1) == 0)
            a = funcs[index]();
        else
            b = funcs[index]();
        if (index > 0)
            //The short-circuiting behavior we intend to have
            if (a && b)
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    bool evaluation = evaluate_vec({ A, B, C, D });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem with Template Meta-Programming!

```
//If we run out of functions and didn't find a pair that both returned true, we return false
bool evaluate_impl(bool) {
    return false;
}

//At this point, we're guaranteed to have at least 1 cached result and 1 unevaluated function call.
template<typename Func, typename ... Funcs>
bool evaluate_impl(bool cached, Func && func, Funcs&& ... funcs) {
    //store the result of the function
    bool result = func();
    if (cached && result)
        return true;
    else {
        //the result of this call becomes the new cached value
        return evaluate_impl(result, std::forward<Funcs>(funcs)...);
    }
}

//We receive all the functions
template<typename Func, typename ... Funcs>
bool evaluate_tmp(Func && func, Funcs&& ... funcs) {
    //We cache the result of calling the first function and pass along to the next step
    return evaluate_impl(func(), std::forward<Funcs>(funcs)...);
}

int main() {
    bool result = evaluate_tmp(A, B, C, D);
}
```

This efficiently expands to support any number of function calls (up to what your compiler will allow, at any rate).

```
int main() {
    bool result = evaluate_tmp(A, B, A, C, A, A, A, A, D, A, B, A, C, A, D, A);
}
```